# Is loading the stack pointer with a value a privileged instruction?

Tags: c, operating-system, elf

This question confused a lot. I got this question from my mid-term as a TF question.

Really hope someone can tell me why, Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking *if* it's a privileged instruction, or *why* it's a privileged instruction, or something else altogether? And keep the title as a short summary of your main problem, which is asked about in the body of the question.

Comment: Please consult your OS and processor user manual.  Usually, no, since it's required for local stack frames.

Comment: What thoughts do you have about this? What is the stack pointer used for? Who needs to change it? Why? What happens when it is changed? Is the user process affected when it changes? Are other processes affected when it changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every processor I know of, the answer is NO. If it were, you applications could not allocate memory on the stack.

```
MOV  SP, BP
ADD  #32, SP
```

or free up the memory

```
MOV BP, SP
```